# Images from a gallery crop or dissapear in different screen sizes

Tags: css, wordpress, styles, image-gallery

first of all I am not web developer, not web designer.. Just know how to use wordpress themes and very little css modifications. So sorry I say something stupid.

I am using narrative app for doing some image galleries. So you upload photos in their app in a very cool way then they create a link to be pasted in a html text block.

So, the problem is. In some screens like Mac 27", some images are cropped, if you decrease screen size manually you can see even some pictures that start to get so small and also dissapear. If you refresh in some screens this will look ok, but in other like imac 27" some images will still appear cropped.

You can see here:
https://frandeprado.com/prueba-dosmasenlamesa   (i am testing so I dont know what you will see, but I suppose you will probably know what is the problem).

I tried this css, so this makes images not to crop but the cool align they had dissapears. I like the way some pictures are align on top, others botton, other left..right..etc (you can see in the link)

```
.nar-block {
    xbackground-position-x: center !important;
    xbackground-position-y: center !important;
    }
```

This is actual CSS with no modifications from one of the photos

```
.nar-block-7N8412fP7TJ5YCUY1 {
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  margin-right: 15px !important;
  margin-top: 51px !important;
  margin-bottom: 15px !important;
  opacity: 0 !important;
  transition: margin-top 0.8s, opacity 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-top: 44.447659697605445% !important;
  flex: 0.2963177313173696 !important;
  background-size: 60.59951186180115% auto;
  background-position-x: 58.02273236020537px;
  background-position-y: 67.15377749249006px;
}
```

I have seen something in css something called flex, but I dont even know how it works. When I uncheck some of this in google console, I see some changes.. But as we say in Spain, this sound chinesse to me..

So I hope you can help me to solve this with an easy solution.

Thank you very much

Comment: you have bad code. you need to redo the technical module. I can do it.

Comment: I am on a badget so I am trying to do it by myself,  is it posible to do it with some easy css?

Comment: my main language is Russian. maybe I misunderstood somewhere. but the best is to Rewrite the Plugin code. I can do what you want for any screens for a fee. If you need it, you can contact me. Success to you.

Answer (score 0):

**Your plugin has very bad, large, completely unnecessary toxic code. If you are happy with this ugly code. Then you can make a simple css solution:**

```
.wpb_wrapper img.nar-block  {
        background-size: cover !important;
        background-position: center !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir, thanks for your code. But this makes images align all together. I like this big gaps and not align photos. I did it that way in an gallery app. So when adding background-size cover it makes images big again. second line is one of the better options I have found for the moment, but I just put .nar-block. Is it better to put img.nar-blok? Tanks for your time.. Lets see if I find how to do it to stay as it is now.. :)